# Place cursor at the end of an iframe content 

Tags: javascript, iframe, focus, cursor

I have an iframe in which I want to add images dynamically with php. 
Each image should be followed by a line break and so that the next image added to be added in the following row. The line break is added but the focus stays always at the beginning of the iframe content (when it should have been at the end of the newly added `<br>` tag). 
Is there a way to move the cursor to the end of the content of the iframe with Javascript which works with all browsers?

Comment: Please share the code that's working for IE and FF

Comment: I rephrased the question since that was not really the point. The solution I made for IE & FF was respectively adding the line break (before or after) according to the position of the cursor. The most important question is how to move the cursor at the end of the iframe content in every case.

Comment: An `<input>` with opacity 0 at the end of the content? Call `.focus()` after any content is loaded.

Comment: I would really like to avoid adding an <input> in my content cause it is part of something bigger that will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting scrollTop or calling scrollTo?